# Using Color Commands for Math Operators

Tags: color, math-operators

I was wanting to know how is it possible to create a math symbol in color to position correctly. I have used the following but the top limit does not center properly. Sorry for the verbage as I don't know how to word the question precise and clearly. Here is a `mwe` of the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\[ \sum_{\color{red} m=0}^{\color{red}{\infty}}  \]

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following below:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\textcolor` instead, such as

```
\[ \sum_{\textcolor{red}{m=0}}^{\textcolor{red}{\infty}}  \]
```

[image: color in math example]

`\color` is a switch / declaration, it requires grouping to limit its effect such as by additional curly braces. `\textcolor` affects just its argument and works for math as well.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I did that but not for both. I thought since `color` worked for the lower limit I could leave that alone and alter the top limit by doing this.                              `\[  \sum_{\color{red}{m=0}^{\textcolor{red}{\infty}}  \]`. But I see now that does not work :) Thanks for the quick response.